# Terminal lettering randomly bunches up and has spaces

Tags: terminal

[image]

As you can see, it looks messed up. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have set your terminal to use a variable width font.

To resolve the problem, change the terminal font to a fixed width (monospace) font.